# Is there a way to figure out what code is using an Assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio project that is including a mystery dll (Microsoft.Contracts.dll) in my bin/Release folder when I build.  This assembly isn't in my references folder, I have searched all of the DLLs I am using using reflector and none of those are using it either.  Is there some way I can determine what is using this assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It should show you which DLLs (including .NET ones, not just your own) have which dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly `Microsoft.Conctract.dll` is coming from Microsoft's [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/default.aspx).

Are you using those in your source code?

Comment: I don't think so.  If I was, wouldn't I have to include a reference to `Microsoft.Contracts.dll`?

Comment: ... or another assembly references `Microsoft.Conctract.dll`.